# SQL Pivot Table not getting consolidated records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want this output

[image]

I want to get unique with group by PortFolio Code but not getting the dessired output.
I am getting following output. Please tell me where I have to use pivot or to get proper output

[image]

Here is my query

```
    select isnull('PortFolio Code: '+a.CPORTFOLIOCODE,'Total'),
(select sum(a.FOSAMT) where a.SZBUCKETCODE=1) as [Bucket :1],
(select sum(a.FOSAMT) where a.SZBUCKETCODE=2) as [Bucket :2],
(select sum(a.FOSAMT) where a.SZBUCKETCODE=3) as [Bucket :3] 
from dbo.COL_TRN_AGREEMENT a 
group by a.CPORTFOLIOCODE,a.SZBUCKETCODE 
with rollup
```

I tried to use pivot but failed to get through.

Comment: You desired results dont jive with what you have.In bucket2 for desired results you have 0 for Portofolio C in atula results you have 823670.56.So you need to SUM it or what?Also all those table tags are unnecessary.

Comment: I want to rollup(Sum) at the end of it. I just want to get unique [Portfolio code]. As per the group by [Portfolio code] I want Sum of [Bucket 1],[Bucket 2] and [Bucket 3]

Comment: Can u create schema and enter some dummy data in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35490)?? It'll help us to give accurate answer...

Comment: @Mihai - The table tags are so you click "run code snippet" and get the html table.

Comment: @MartinSmith Nifty little trick for css,html type questions,here are a bit distracting.Maybe it`s just me.

Comment: @Mihai - Yes. Shame that the actual HTML tags can't be hidden.

Comment: I want to get group by PortFolio code and sum of bucket values

Comment: @KrishnrajRana [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43d02/2) its the link for SQL fiddle.

Comment: @AMS: Yes, i checked the link but it would be great if you could enter some dummy data in sql fiddle. you can insert data in "Build Schema" section.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Hey I am not able to insert. It is having 209 columns. it will get some time to insert into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed with rollup and doing case based aggregation.

```
select isnull('PortFolio Code: '+a.CPORTFOLIOCODE,'Total'),
sum(case when a.SZBUCKETCODE =1  then a.FOSAMT else 0 end ) as [Bucket :1],
sum(case when a.SZBUCKETCODE =2  then a.FOSAMT else 0 end ) as [Bucket :2],
sum(case when a.SZBUCKETCODE =3  then a.FOSAMT else 0 end ) as [Bucket :3]
from dbo.COL_TRN_AGREEMENT a 
group by a.CPORTFOLIOCODE
```

Comment: Perfect buddy :) Just what I needed

Comment: Hi can I now use Rollup after this to get total of all bucketwise

Comment: add sum(a.SZBUCKETCODE) as [AllBuckets] to the column list. in case you have buckets other than 1,2,3 then sum(case when a.SZBUCKETCODE  in (1,2,3)  then a.FOSAMT else 0 end ) as [AllBuckets] should work

Comment: Just have some modification about last rollup that we have to add FOSAMT rather than SZBUCKETCODE. any ways thanks

Comment: hi can it be done without using `rollup`. I mean to say Is their any other way to get this output without `rollup`. I also heard about `CUBE` but not sure How it is implemented.